# Swift json data decode

Tags: json, parsing, swift3

I want to decode below json data. My json data like this:

```
{
"CourseCode": "xxx",
"ChapterNumber": 1,
"CourseName": "yyy",
"UnitName": "zzz",
"QuestionAnswer": [
    {
        "Index": 1,
        "Question": "bla bla",
        "Answer": "bla bla"
    },
    {
        "Index": 2,
        "Question": "bla bla bla",
        "Answer": "bla bla bla"
    }
}
```

And My codes like this:

```
class Question{

let question:String
let answer:String
let questionId:Int

init?(json:JSONDictionary){
    guard let question = json["Question"] as? String,
        let answer = json["Answer"] as? String,
        let questionId = json["Index"] as? Int
        else {return nil}

    self.question = question
    self.answer = answer
    self.questionId = questionId

}

static func get(course:String, unit:Int) -> Resource<[Question]>{
    func parser(json: Any) -> [Question]?{
        guard let dictionary = json as? JSONDictionary,
            let dictionaries = dictionary["QuestionAnswer"] as? JSONArray
            else { return nil }
        return dictionaries.flatMap(Question.init)

    }

    let url = URL(string: "www.www")!
    return Resource<[Question]>(url: url, body: nil, method: "GET", parseJSON: parser)

}
deinit { print("\(question) is being deinitialized") }
}
```

Every thing is ok. But now I want to handle CourseCode, ChapterNumber, CourseName and UnitName. How can I edit my codes for this?

Comment: The values are on the same level as `let dictionaries = dictionary["QuestionAnswer"]`, practically one level higher than `Question`. I regard it as not very reasonable to put the parser into the *child-class*

Comment: @vadian my json structure changed, so it was.

Comment: Nevertheless you can get for example the course code with `let courseCode = dictionary["CourseCode"] as? String` in the `guard` expression of the parser.

Comment: @vadian yes it is possible let courseCode = dictionary["CourseCode"] as? String. But how I should change in Question init?

Comment: In your case I would declare class (static) properties as the values in fact belong to the class.